# How to solve the following problem which has been defined recursively?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I tried touse a recursion so that we can finally arrive at $a_1$. But the recursion gets bigger. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: You can typically find the limit by setting $a_{n+1}=a_n = x$, and solve for $x$ as you would any single-variable equation.

Answer (score 1):

The map
$$T:\quad\bar{\mathbb C}\to\bar{\mathbb C},\qquad z\mapsto{1\over 4-3z}$$
is a Moebius transformation. Solving the equation $T(z)=z$ gives the two fixed points $z_1={1\over3}$ and $z_2=1$ of $T$. One computes $T'(z_1)={1\over3}$ and $T'(z_2)=3$, which means that $z_1$ is an attracting and $z_2$ a repelling fixed point. If we would introduce a new complex coordinate $w$ with $z_1$ corresponding to $w=0$ and $z_2$ to $w=\infty$ the map $T$ would assume the form $\hat T(w)={1\over3}w$.

It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}T^{\circ n}(a)={1\over3}$ for all $a\ne1$, and $T^{\circ n}(1)=1$ $(n\geq1)$.